# Having error while trying to add record mysql table while using postman

Tags: mysql, node.js, postman

```
app.post('/EmployeeDB', (req, res) => {
    let emp = req.body;
    var ss = 'INSERT INTO `employee` (`Name`)VALUES (?) ';
    connection.query(ss, (err, rows, fields) =>{
        if(!err)
            res.send('New employee has been added');
            
        else
            console.log(err)
    })
});
```

Using this code to add data in mysql using nodejs and postman but having this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?)' at line 1",

Comment: [You need to pass some data](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-nodejs/update/) to be used on the `?`

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be providing values to the query. You are saving the request data to the "emp" variable, but not passing the data into the query. Look into how to provide data in a **prepared statement**.

Edit:
When your server receives the data from postman you are storing it in the "emp" variable:

```
let emp = req.body;
```

But this value is never sent to the database in the query.
Your query is:

```
"INSERT INTO `employee` (`Name`)VALUES (?)"
```

Here you want to insert a name to the database, however the "?" here: `VALUES (?)`  means that you need to provide an actual value for the "Name" of the employee as a prepared statement. You need to send both the **query**  and the **data** to the database. You are only sending the query.

```
 connection.query(ss, (err, rows, fields)
```

As you can see you are not sending data from "emp" and not binding it either.
The error you are receiving shows that the database received a "?" instead of actual data to insert to the database (shown in **bold** text):

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> **near '?)'** at line 1",

You should look at how to use a **prepared statement** in the database connector you are using.

Comment: I want to pass the data using postman